# Google Play, Application Icon error

Tags: android, icons, google-play

[image: Icon Error]

Any idea why is it happening to my application on Google Play?

Comment: Did you set the promotional image
180 (l) x 120 (h) ?

Comment: No, only the 512x512 icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

It looks fine on my end, try clearing your cookies or use a different browser. Icons don't just disappear on Google's end.